# How to replace HTML with Native Components in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have an api thats outputting html content mostly `<p>` tags and hrefs. Whats the best way to go about this in React Native? Should they all be converted to `<Text>` components or should I render the HTML using something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider having your api return JSON rather than HTML.  (if this is not possible, then create a second endpoint that returns JSON.)  Once you have the JSON data fetched, you can assemble your UI as needed using the native components that react native provides.